# stopping windows from undoing overclock settings

Tags: windows-7, cpu, overclocking

I have managed to overclock my CPU from 2.5 to 3.0 GHz, my BIOS says so at the top. But when I load coretemp after windows boots, it says my CPU is only at the original 2.5GHz. Is this just coretemp being an idiot, or is windows really turning my CPU speed down? Also, the CPU maxes out at 2.5 when under a heavy load, but won't go any faster according to coretemp. And if windows is the problem, how do I stop it?

I have an AMD Athlon X2 processor and an M3N78-VM motherboard

Comment: nevermind. It was my BIOS being screwy instead.

Comment: that said, Coretemp doesn't show me my overclocked settings. It just reads the manufacturer off the die (or looks it up in a database). If I use speccy though, and look at CPU -> Core0, I can see that it is set to 3800MHz, not 3400 as Coretemp shows.